# Conforming to AVAudioPlayerDelegate

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having some strange troubles conforming to `AVAudioPlayerDelegate`. This following is exactly what I have in a completely new Xcode project:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  let audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    audioPlayer.delegate = self
  }
}

extension ViewController: AVAudioPlayerDelegate {}
```

For some reason I crash every time on the line I set the delegate: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)`

Console is empty.

Comment: Give details about crash.

Comment: You have a typo. `override fun` should be `override func`. Have you tried conforming to the protocol directly? `class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {...}`?

Comment: Sorry about the typo - Conforming via an extension is just as direct as any other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use one of the valid initialisers of `AVAudioPlayer`; `init()` is not one of them (even though it compiles).

The valid ones are:

```
init(contentsOfURL url: NSURL) throws

init(data data: NSData) throws

init(contentsOfURL url: NSURL,
    fileTypeHint utiString: String?) throws

init(data data: NSData,
    fileTypeHint utiString: String?) throws
```

Comment: Thanks. They should really `private` that initializer!

Comment: Indeed! I think though it's actually a compatibility thing with Objective-C, since an empty initialiser doesn't exist for `AVAudioPlayer` when you check the source Xcode generates for it. There's an empty initialiser for `NSObject` which I think is probably what allows it to compile, though in a pure Swift framework it wouldn't count as an initialiser for that class.